# Advanced writing files in Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm figuring out how to create an advanced script to generate JSON files with contents in loop.

I have a simple .csv file looks like in this screenshot:

[image: csv]

Column A is list of counties, Column b is list of cities, in this row it can be parented.

Raw format:

```
Los Angeles,"Los Angeles, Santa Monica, Burbank, Commerce"
Kern,"California City, Bakersfield, Wasco"
Santa Barbara,"Goleta, Santa Barbara, Solvang"
Orange,"Anaheim, Costa Mesa, Irvine"
```

I need to know how to write script to generate JSON files with name of counties, then add cities in content each JSON file.

Excepted output would be in these screenshots:

[image: output1]

Each JSON file should contain list of cities inside, look at this JSON format.

[image: json format]

I have script but it's broken and I couldn't research, it has been like 5 hours.

Any suggestion is welcome

Avoid renaming errors, in that case use `.replace(/ /g, '-')` to replace from white space to "-"

EDIT: I cleaned spaghetti code, I couldn't find my best one but I think thats

```
var lr = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: require('fs').createReadStream('source/counties.csv')
});

lr.on('line', function (line) {
    var names = rawFile.responseText.split("\n")

    names.forEach(function(name) {
        list.push({city: capitalizeFirstLetter(city),  colony:name.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"")});
    })
    console.log(JSON.stringify(list));
    var fileName = selected.replace(/ /g, '-').toLowerCase();
    fs.writeFileSync(fileName + ".json", '');
});
```

Comment: Show us what you have so far

Comment: and your problem while implementing this was ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var fs = require('fs');

function writeToFiles(input) {
    fs.readFile(input, function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        data = data.toString();
        data.split('\n').forEach(function (line) {
            var parsed = line.split(/([\w ]+),"([\w ,]+)"/).filter(function (e) {
                return !!e;
            });
            var countryName = parsed[0];
            var cities = parsed[1];
            var cityArray = eval("['" + cities.split(",").join("', '") + "']");
            var result = [];
            cityArray.forEach(function (e) {
                result.push({
                    country: countryName,
                    city: e.trim()
                });
            });
            fs.writeFileSync('./' + countryName.replace(/[ ]/g, '-') + '.json', JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
        });
    });
}
```

It uses pure NodeJS, without anything else. With you input, it gives this:

[image]

And this is `Los-Angeles.json`:

```
[
    {
        "country": "Los Angeles",
        "city": "Los Angeles"
    },
    {
        "country": "Los Angeles",
        "city": "Santa Monica"
    },
    {
        "country": "Los Angeles",
        "city": "Burbank"
    },
    {
        "country": "Los Angeles",
        "city": "Commerce"
    }
]
```

To use it, do this:

```
writeToFiles('input.csv');
```

Comment: It worked, it's definetly accepted answer but what's going on with your account?

Comment: @Ivan you can find the person who created the account and have a chat with him [here](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/721/shadows-den), he's known as UniKitty in there. :)